# Parse responsexml in salesforce

Tags: soap-api, integration, xml, xmlparsing

I am integrating salesforce with an external SAP Application and I am getting the following response XML

```
 <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header />
    <SOAP:Body xmlns:syn="http://bcn.com/SAP/SalesForce">
       <n0:MT_Syngene_SAP_Res xmlns:n0="http://bcn.com/SAP/SalesForce/....." xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:......">
          <Records>
             <EXTERNAL_NUM>0000200196</EXTERNAL_NUM>
          </Records>
       </n0:MT_Syngene_SAP_Res>
    </SOAP:Body>
  </SOAP:Envelope>
```

I am trying to use the following piece of code to parse the response

```
 Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
             doc.load(response.getBody());
             Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();
             dom.XmlNode strSuccessful= root.getChildElement('SOAP:Body xmlns:syn="http://biocon.com/SAP/SalesForce/Syngene"', null);
        System.debug('*****&&&&&'+strSuccessful);
```

However, strSuccessful value is coming as null in the debug.

Is this the correct way of parsing the return xml? I am trying to get EXTERNAL_NUM value, that comes in the response xml.

Answer (score 0):

The child does not include attributes or anything else within its name. The more appropriate method should look like this:

```
dom.XmlNode strSuccessful= root.getChildElement(
   'Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
);
```

Where the first parameter is the case-sensitive name of the element (not including the namespace) and the second is the URI of the namespace.

Comment: But when I am trying to use the same approach and get the inner node values, that is again coming up as null. The following piece of code :            
dom.XmlNode strSuccessful= root.getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/').getChildElement('n0','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

Comment: @user55791 It works for me. Make sure the names are correct.